# Avoiding layout displacement after SystemTray visibility changes

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml

I'm trying to avoid the vertical displacement of the main layout when the upper WP7 SystemTray gets shown or hidden by an user action.

I've been trying to combine the visibility change of the SystemTray with adding a margin to the main layout like so

```
SystemTray.IsVisible = false;
LayoutRoot.Margin = new Thickness(0, 32, 0, 0);
```

But the result, as expected, isn't very smooth. I suppose there's something could help xaml-side, but still haven't found what I'm looking for. So..  Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep a grid say `grid1` of 32 pixels (same as that of the system tray) in height on top of layout root. And keep opacity of `SystemTray` as `0.99` such that the system tray overlaps the `grid1`. Now when its visibility is false, the grid1 will takeover. I haven't tried this, its just a thought which I guess should work. All the best.

The grid height/width will change when user changes orientation (if that is what you are going to do in your app), that has to be kept in mind.

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm, never thought on that simple idea.